# How to change value output after edit Nestable

Tags: php, html, css, jquery-nestable

Example:

> `https://codepen.io/upgrayedd/pen/OXwAXO`

( I copy it )
My project is same that example.

Problem is I need change data-id ( or data-name, data-slug, data-* ... )

But I don't know how to output.

Output:

> `[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":1},{"id":2}]` ( In that example )

My output need:

> `[{"id":10},{"id":4},{"id":1},{"id":2}]`

( id = 10 changed from my edit );

I try

`$('#nestable2').nestable('serialize');`

But it keeps old Output

> `[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":1},{"id":2}]`

AND SORRY FOR A POOR ENGLISH. THANK A LOT.

Comment: `<tr class="dd-item" data-id="10">
      <td class="dd-handle">Item 3</td>
    </tr>` Change this

Comment: Yes, <tr class="dd-item" data-id="10"> <td class="dd-handle">Item 3</td> </tr> is changed ( f12, element changed ). But how to update output JSON nestable, It keep old output ( [{id:3}] ). => I need output [{id:10}]. @@!

Comment: Here i changed just the data-id attr and it worked : [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqPyeo)

Comment: Not that's @Ryan Hunt. But I found solution here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXVrPN . Thank All

Comment: and one more thing to heppen is ".attr" and ".data" this is !IMPORTANT.